# What is the latest most stable version of Java after Java 8?

Tags: java, version

Almost all the Java applications are now moved to Java 8 as it is the least most stable version of Java. Looking to know which will be the next most stable version? Is it Java 11 or more than that?

I read lot of articles but I am very confused about the next most stable version of Java as some refer to Java 11 as the least stable version and some mention that Java 21.

Comment: The LTS versions are 8, 11, 17 and 21. Non-LTS versions are not supported as soon as the next release is published (so basically after ~6 months). All versions are "stable" since they all pass the TCK.

Comment: What is that you find confusing?

Comment: the "latest" and the "most stable" is kind of opposite of each other - the latest is Java 23, but that is early access, not stable - if you want more stable, you must take earlier versions. As of now, Java 21 is the latest released (non early-access) one

Comment: The reason applications are sticking with Java 8 has nothing to do with its stability.  They are sticking with 8 because it was the last version of Java that allowed illicit, improper hacks of the Java SE library.  Authors of other libaries were warned for years that they should not do that, but they decided it was cool and “clever” to do it regardless, and now applications which use those libraries are stuck.

Comment: What did you find when you went to the official Java website? And what do you mean by "most stable"?

Answer (score 4):

### Every version of Java is stable and reliable

The [Java specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html) are updated on a six-month cadence, per the “release train” model used for several years now.

- Finalized features are included.
- Features not yet complete are held back for possible inclusion in the next release, six months later, when the next train leaves the station.

Implementations of the [Java specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) follow this same six-month cadence. (See [FAQ](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/post/update-and-faq-on-the-java-se-release-cadence).) The most important of the implementations is the open-source codebase at the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project. However that project publishes only source code, not binaries nor installers.

For JDK products delivered as binaries or installers, choose from any of several vendors:

- Adoptium by the Eclipse Foundation
- IBM
- Red Hat
- Amazon
- Azul Systems
- Microsoft
- BellSoft
- Oracle
- SAP
- … and more

Most of the [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit)/[JRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)#Java_Runtime_Environment) products from various vendors are based largely, if not entirely, on the OpenJDK codebase.

All of these JDK products are thoroughly tested. Nearly all have been tested by the [*Technology Compatibility Kit (TCK)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_Compatibility_Kit). Some are also subjected to the [*Eclipse AQAvit™*](https://adoptium.net/aqavit/) test suite.

So every JDK product from any of these vendors is high quality and production ready. You can always deploy the latest release of Java.

Your confusion may come from the fact that most releases of Java are supported for a short time only. The support period typically runs from launch to a few months after the succeeding version’s launch, for a total of about nine months. That is generally the case, though each vendor makes their own support policy. Any vendor may offer extended support, perhaps for a fee.

#### Long-Term Support (LTS) versions

Every few years a particular version of Java may be designated by the vendors as a [Long-Term Support (LTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version. Historically, the community of JDK vendors has followed the lead of Oracle in making this LTS declaration. So we have seen an LTS every three years in the past, and [every two years currently](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/post/moving-the-jdk-to-a-two-year-lts-cadence). The LTS versions include:

- Java 8
- Java 11
- Java 17
- [Java 21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_21)

See [*Java version history*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) at Wikipedia for details.

Be very clear though: These LTS versions are *not* any more reliable or stable than the other versions. Every version of Java is feature-complete, and of the highest quality. The LTS versions are *not* any more important or better than the short-lived versions. The LTS designation is an arbitrary one, based on the calendar, not on quality.

Java is perhaps the most thoroughly examined and well tested software ever made (outside of specialty fields such as aerospace or military).

#### Development & deployment choices

Many Java developers make a habit of developing and/or testing with the latest version of Java to ensure compatibility. Some developers limit deployment to LTS versions only, while others with rapid releases may choose to always use the latest version.

The choice is yours to make based on your development and deployment situation, without concern for the quality of any particular Java version.